# Код выдает ошибку Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 12 at Triangle.main(Triangle.java:24)

Tags: java, массивы, исключения

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Triangle {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int t = in.nextInt(), number,k=0, sum=0;
        int[] otvet = new int[t];
        int[] parameters = new int[t*3];

        for(int i = 0; i<parameters.length;i++){ // цикл заполняет массив всеми числами.
            number = in.nextInt();
            parameters[i] = number;
        // System.out.print(" " +parameters[i]);

        }

        System.out.println();

        for (int i = 0; i < t; i++) {
        int[] meanings = new int[t];
        meanings[i] = parameters[i*k]*parameters[i*k+1]+parameters[i*k+2];
        System.out.print(" "+ meanings[i]);
            for ( ; meanings[i]!=0; meanings[i]/=10){
                sum += meanings[i]%10;}
                otvet[i] = sum;
            k += 3;
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас неправильно построен последний цикл: при одном и том же проходе цикла увеличивается одновременно и номер ответа (`i`), и смещение, которое вы добавляете к номеру ответа для доступа к элементам массива параметров (`k`). В результате, например, при трех тройках параметров (`t == 3, parameters.length == 9`) при третьем проходе цикла переменные принимают значения `i = 2, k = 6` и при попытке вычислить выражение

```
  meanings[i] = parameters[i * k] * parameters[i * k + 1] + parameters[i * k + 2];
```

первый же индекс вычисляется как `i * k == 2 * 6 == 12`, при размере массива, равной 9.

Представьте себе параметры не в виде линейного массива, а в виде матрицы, в которой каждая *i*-тая строка содержит массив параметров для вычисления *i*-того   ответа, и в уме прикиньте алгоритм прохода по элементам этой матрицы и способ вычисления индексов для доступа к массиву, и тогда вы легко сообразите, что ваша задача естественным образом решается при помощи вложенных циклов - внешний цикл обходит все строки, а вложенный в него внутренний -- все параметры внутри одной строки.

И кстати, я бы советовал вам давать более осмысленные имена переменным и форматировать код более или менее стандартным образом -- делать единообразные отступы и вставлять пробелы между операндами и знаками операций. Тогда ваш код будет выглядеть намного опрятнее и вам же самому будет намного легче в нем разбираться, не говоря уж о посторонних читателях.

И еще, кстати -- вы, кажется, немного запутались в своих массивах -- массив `otvet` заполняется, но не используется, а внутренний цикл

```
  for ( ; meanings[i] != 0; meanings[i] /= 10) { ... }
```

выглядит довольно загадочно -- если то же самое записать с помощью оператора `while`, то ваши намерения будет видны намного более отчетливо (imho).

Answer (score 0):

> `int[] parameters = new int[t*3];`

Последний элемент массива имеет индекс `t * 3 - 1`

> ```
> for (int i = 0; i < t; i++) {
>   ........
>   k += 3;
> }
> ```

За каждую итерацию цикла `k` увеличивается на 3.

> ```
> meanings[i] = parameters[i * k] * parameters[i * k + 1] + parameters[i * k + 2];
> ```

На последней итерации `i = t - 1`, `k = (t - 1) * 3`

Подставим эти значения в выражение для индексов

```
meanings[t - 1] = parameters[(t - 1) * (t - 1) * 3] * parameters[(t - 1) * (t - 1) * 3 + 1] + parameters[(t - 1) * (t - 1) * 3 + 2];
(t - 1) * (t - 1) * 3 = 3 * (t * t - 2 * t + 1) = 3 * t * t - 6 * t + 3
meanings[t - 1] = parameters[3 * t * t - 6 * t + 3] * parameters[3 * t * t - 6 * t + 4] + parameters[3 * t * t - 6 * t + 5];
```

Максимальный индекс здесь `3 * t * t - 6 * t + 5`

Решая неравенство

```
3 * t * t - 6 * t + 5 <= t * 3 - 1
```

получаем

```
3 * t * t - 6 * t + 6 <= t * 3
t * t - 2 * t + 2 <= t
t * t - 3 * t + 2 <= 0
```

`t * t - 3 * t + 2 = 0` - парабола. Ветви направлены вверх. Корни t<sub>0</sub> = 1, t<sub>1</sub> = 2

Решения исходного неравенства лежат на отрезке [1, 2]. Т.к. `t` целое, то исходное неравенство выполняется, а значит и программа работает без ошибок, только при `t = 1` или `t = 2`

Comment: верно, но сложно.